# My collapsing bar lmage is not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

In my online food ordering app,in food detail section the image is not in right position.I am importing it from firebase database.

This is my fooddetail.java code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.admin.clicknorder.FoodDetail"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="#0d0e0d"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
       >


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"

        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:title="Food Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/btnCart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:useCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nesterScrollView"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="Food Name"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_price"
                        android:layout_weight="9"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1,000"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:id="@+id/number_button"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    app:textSize="8sp"
                    app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:initialNumber="1"
                    app:finalNumber="20"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/food_description"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="description"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I don't know what is happening but if it is anything related to image resolution and size,please tell how can i fix it from android studio itself.

[image: The image is looking like this]

If any more details will require...i will edit my question.
Thank you

Comment: did u solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You have just placed your **`ImageView`** and **`Toolbar`** in wrong place

Move your `image_food` **`ImageView`** and **`Toolbar`** inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

### Change your layout like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title=""
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_food"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/kid_goku"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_message"
        app:useCompatPadding="true" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nesterScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/food_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:text="Food Name"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout_price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/food_price"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="9"
                            android:text="1,000"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        app:backGroundColor="@color/colorAccent"
                        app:finalNumber="20"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:textSize="8sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/food_description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:text="description"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**RESULT**

[image]